# firewall: 2-way UDP communication possible?

Tags: networking, udp, firewall

If a client inside firewall connects to a public server through TCP, once the connection is formed, the firewall allows two-way communication. This is what we normally see in our daily usage. My question is: is this also true for UDP?

Since UDP does not have connect, I will modify the question a little bit...

Suppose the client inside firewall sends a UDP packet to a public server, can the server respond back through firewall using the source address and port of incoming packet?

Comment: Search for "UDP firewall punch" and see [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching). Many firewalls/NATs allow this (so that UDP remains viable from inside->outside) ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is called NAT traversal (or UDP punch through) and works in a similar way to TCP - the stateful NAT device is aware you recently sent a UDP packet from a certain end point internally to a certain end point outside and for a period will accept UDP packets from the same outside endpoint and forward them to the same internal end point.

I always prefer the IETF docs than the plethora of conflicting information out there (including on this site):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128

UPDATE: There are other techniques to "UDP hole punching" such as UPnP's Internet Gateway Protocol and PCP. Each has their advantages and disadvantages and I am afraid there is no one solution works on all NATs!